# PHPExcel formulas goes a mess

Tags: phpexcel

Following code removes three rows at the top and saves xls to new file. But all formulas are destroyed. I need to remove three rows and all columns after D and keep formula values in columns C and D. C and D column formulas comes from E and F columns. But because E and F is removed, it will mess up C and D. How to fix this?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT & ~E_NOTICE);
require_once('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
//Defining File Type
$fileType = "Excel5";
//Retrieving File
$tmpfname = "tasoituslista.xls";
$tmpfname2 = "tasoituslista2.xls";
//Loading file into PHPExcel
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($tmpfname);
$worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); //Worksheet of file defined as first
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow(1, 3);

//Write file into original file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($tmpfname2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, if a formula use data from cells that are being removed, it will break the formula.

You have a couple of options.

- Don't remove columns E and F, but hide them.... the formula will still work, but the values it uses will be hidden
- Before you remove columns E and F, get the calculated values for your formula cells, and update the formula cells with that value, so it isn't a formula cell anymore, but contains the actual value